# c# - Sophisticated 'Find Usages' scenario

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Let's assume I have the following classes in my project:

1. Base interface

   ```
   public interface IInvoker
   {
       void Invoke();
   }
   ```
2. Two classes implementing the interface

   The first one:

   ```
   public class Invoker1 : IInvoker
   {
       public void Invoke()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Invoker #1");
       }
   }
   ```

   And the second:

   ```
   public class Invoker2 : IInvoker
   {
       public void Invoke()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Invoker #2");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Additionally I have a class which has a field of the interface type:

   ```
   public class InvokerContainer
   {
       private readonly IInvoker target;

       public InvokerContainer(IInvoker invoker)
       {
           this.target = invoker;
       }

       public void InvokeTarget()
       {
           this.target.Invoke();
       }
   }
   ```

The client code looks as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InvokingMethod1(new Invoker1());
        InvokingMethod2(new Invoker2());
        new InvokerContainer(new Invoker1()).InvokeTarget();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void InvokingMethod1(IInvoker invoker)
    {
        invoker.Invoke();
    }

    private static void InvokingMethod2(IInvoker invoker)
    {
        invoker.Invoke();
    }
}
```

So my question is: Is there any way to find all places where `Invoker1#Invoke` is used and what is a possible invocation hierarchy?
With the code above, this approach should give the following results:

1. Calling method: `Program#InvokingMethod1`. The stacktrace: `Program#Main`->`Program#InvokingMethod1` line 17
2. Calling method: `InvokerContainer#InvokeTarget`. The stacktrace: `Program#Main`->`InvokerContainer#InvokeTarget` line 14

Comment: Get a resharper

Comment: @T.S.  I've got it but neither 'Find Usages Advanced' nor 'Search with pattern' helped me. Maybe you know what exactly I should do with Resharper to get the desired result?

Comment: @DmitrySenin , you can't and rightly so as per SOLID principles (Liskov substitution in particular). Interfaces are there to allow design by contract and it should be agnostic of class implementation. Using interface methods of class directly (not via interface) is beginning of bad code smell. If you are looking at mess created by somebody else then wish you good luck :)

Comment: @sbp , I'm not going to violate Liskov substitution principle :) I am looking for a tool which can help to analyze the code like above deeply

Comment: ReSharper feature "Incoming Calls" can show hierarchy, but it won't filter invocation of interfaces